# upgrading from spree 1-3 to 2-0-stable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am going to upgrade a spree application from 1.3 to spree version 2-0-stable. anyone can please explain the exact steps or link to follow. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first.  Ensure you have a backup of your data, and make sure you test the migration in a development environment before attempting to do so in production.

Update your Gemfile to pull from the spree 2-0-stable branch:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable'
```

and then run

```
bundle update spree
```

If you are using any extensions, you will need to upgrade those to 2.0 compatible versions as well.

Assuming all that worked, your next step will be to upgrade your schema to the 2.0 version by running:

```
rake railties:install:migrations
rake db:migrate
```

If all of that worked, you should be able to start up a rails server running on Spree 2.0.

If you have applied any customizations to Spree you should familiarize yourself with the [Spree 2.0.0 Release Notes](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/release_notes/spree_2_0_0.html) as you may find that those customizations don't work as well as they used to.

Give it a try in your development environment, fix any issues you have, test it out, and then move on to doing it on your production server.  Just remember to save backups!

Good luck!